# The submenu is in front of the main menu

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Here is my `.html` code :

```
{% load i18n %}
<div class="customer-context-menu closed {% if customer.gender == 0 %}male{% else %}female{% endif %}">
    <b class="unselectable">
        {{ customer.icon }}
        {{ user.get_full_name }}
    </b>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:perceptions" cust=customer.pk %}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false">{% trans "Perceptions" %}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:profile" cust=customer.pk %}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false">{% trans "Profile" %}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:alerts_index" cust=customer.pk %}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false">{% trans "Alerts" %}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:messaging" cust=customer.pk %}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false">{% trans "Messaging" %}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:requests" cust=customer.pk %}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false">{% trans "Requests" %}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:documents" cust=customer.pk %}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false">{% trans "Documents" %}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:logs" cust=customer.pk %}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false">{% trans "Logs" %}</a></li>
        <li class="separator"></li>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:loan" cust=customer.pk pk=loan.pk%}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false">{% trans "Loan" %}</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"># Loan </a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>{% trans "Perceptions" %}</a></li>
                <li><a>{% trans "Perceptions" %}</a></li>
                <li><a>{% trans "Perceptions" %}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="separator"></li>
        {% if customer.phone_1 %}
        <li class="phone">{{ customer.phone_1 }}</li>
        {% endif %}
        <li><a href="mailto:{{ user.email }}" data-turbolinks="false"><i class="material-icons">email</i> {{ user.email }}</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url "customers:print" cust=customer.pk %}" class="unselectable" data-turbolinks="false" target="_blank"><i class="material-icons">printer</i> {% trans "Print" %}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want with this code to get a multi level drop down menu (e.g., http://red-team-design.com/dist/uploads/2011/03/css3-multi-level-dropdown-menu.png).

I just don't know how to fix my issue with css code. Here is what I obtain so far in image : [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnip0.png). The submenu is located in front of the main menu while it should be on the right side. How could I fix such issue?

Thanks in advance!

**P.S.** Please let me know if the question is unclear.

---

```
.customer-context-menu b {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 14px 2px 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap; }
  .customer-context-menu b .material-icons {
    float: left;
    margin: -3px 4px 0 -5px; }
.customer-context-menu .phone {
  padding: 10px 10px !important;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: normal; }
.customer-context-menu.female b {
  border-color: #ffcbe5;
  color: #ff65b1; }
.customer-context-menu.female:hover b {
  background-color: #fff4f9; }
.customer-context-menu.female.open b {
  background-color: #ff65b1;
  color: white; }
.customer-context-menu.female.open i {
  color: white; }
.customer-context-menu.female.open ul li a:hover {
  color: #ff65b1; }
.customer-context-menu.female.open .separator {
  background-color: #ff65b1; }
.customer-context-menu.male b {
  border-color: #90bfea;
  color: #3a8dda; }
.customer-context-menu.male:hover b {
  background-color: #e6f0fa; }
.customer-context-menu.male.open b {
  background-color: #3a8dda;
  color: white; }
.customer-context-menu.male.open i {
  color: white; }
.customer-context-menu.male.open ul li a:hover {
  color: #3a8dda; }
.customer-context-menu.male.open .separator {
  background-color: #3a8dda; }
.customer-context-menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px 0 0 -6px;
  padding: 6px 0;
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 14px #999;
  background-color: #f4f4f4 !important; }
  .customer-context-menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1px 10px;
    min-width: 300px; }
  .customer-context-menu ul li.tip:after {
    top: -10px;
    right: 50px;
    bottom: auto;
    left: auto;
    border-width: 0 9px 9px;
    border-color: #bbb transparent;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    border-style: solid;
    content: "";
    left: 10px;
    width: 0; }
.customer-context-menu.open b, .customer-context-menu.open ul {
  background: #def; }
.customer-context-menu.open ul {
  display: block; }
  .customer-context-menu.open ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    padding: 2px 0; }
    .customer-context-menu.open ul li:last-child, .customer-context-menu.open ul li.tip, .customer-context-menu.open ul li.separator {
      border: 0; }
    .customer-context-menu.open ul li.separator {
      padding: 4px; }
    .customer-context-menu.open ul li a {
      cursor: pointer; }
      .customer-context-menu.open ul li a .material-icons {
        color: #888;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        position: relative;
        top: 4px;
        color: inherit; }
      .customer-context-menu.open ul li a:hover {
        background-color: white; }
```

Comment: Add some id for your ul container, f.e. mainUl or what and then try  add float:right for your element (#mainUl { float: right}). Its hard to advice something without code snippet(html+css).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally a full working snippet with the issue isolated would be best, but considering this is not the case, I'll share a basic example with the desired behavior which should be pretty straight forward to integrate.

```css
.main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
}

.main:hover .sub {
  display: block;
}

.sub {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background: gainsboro;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.sub:hover .sub2 {
  display: block;
}

.sub2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  top: -18px;
  left: 200px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  main menu
  <div class="sub">
    first sub menu
    <div class="sub2">
      right sub menu
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As ALL you menu's "ul" elements are positionned in "absolute", You need to add an offset to your submenus about the same size of your first level links width if you don't want them to be superposed to there parents :

```
.customer-context-menu ul ul { left: 300px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is snippet i used last time for similar situation. Maybe it will be usefull.

```
// its clear and well commented code
```

https://jsfiddle.net/csswizardry/Zj4eb/